# I am trying to implement postgres CRUD operations using library - postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, crud, npm-package

I could not find anything for resolving it in the documentation. Could you please help resolving that.

My code base is as below

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const postgres = require('postgres');
const sql = require('./controller/postgres_connection.js');

app.get('/user/insert', async (req, res) => {
    const userID = 'UserName';
    const password = 'S0m3P@$$word';
    await console.log(getUserDetails(userID, password)) 
    res.send('Connection Established. Check logs');
})
async function getUserDetails({ userID, password }) {
    try{    
        const users = await sql`
        insert into application_form
        (uid, password)
        values
        (${ userID }, ${ password })
         returning uid, password
        `
        return users
    }catch(error){
        `your text`
         console.log(error);
    }
}

//While attempting I am getting 

TypeError: sql is not a function
    at getUserDetails (C:\Users\...\Projekt\node\Dubai\index.js:127:28)
```

Comment: You may be missed the function import.  install `npm install pg-sql` and import `const { sql } = require('pg-sql');
`

Comment: can you show the imports that you have? 

It sounds like you either didn't import the `sql`.

Comment: This is the library I am using

```const postgres = require('postgres');```

Into package.json

```"postgres": "^3.3.4"```